# Background running task in server using c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm currently developing a client server application. The client is an android platform, and server is Microsoft sql server. I'm doing the server side coding in c#. In my server side I need to create a task which executes infinitely on my server. I have a datetime column in my database, I need to take datetime values one by one and check it with the current date and time. If the current date and time is greater than the selected date time from the database, then I need to enter that row of the database into another table using insert query. This is the task which I have to create and this task should be executed and checked every one minute in the server. But I have heard that when trying to create a background process, we must make sure that the main thread does not freeze while executing the background process. I'm new to the world of c# and I have tried created many times the background worker and its failing all over. Can some one please show me how to create a background task in server. Thanks in advance for the help..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than coding this yourself from scratch why not use a quality solution that already exists.

Enter [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

A simple example from their website:

```
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, can you please tell me where I have to give this code. I'm new to the c# language, can  you please help me out..

Comment: I recommend just going through their code tutorials, they are quite simple and they will help you understand how to use their code and write some C# at the sam etime.

Comment: Are you doing web or windows or console development?

Comment: I don't know where to put this trigger code in my server code.

Comment: Again, go through the tutorials to really understand what you are doing. I would put this code in my global.ashx.cs in the Application_Start method, that way it would schedule it when your application starts.